# Excel macro run for a list of accounts and save the results

Tags: excel

I need to open an excel file *Excel_No_1*, input in one specific cell one by one account numbers from another excel file *Excel_no_2* and then to press a button on excel *Excel_No_1* to run a script which will populate other fields with some results. It is possible to automate this and save the results for each output for all accounts from *Excel_No_2*. Excel No 1 can be used only once for each account, needs to be closed and open again for any new value from *Excel_No_2*? Thanks a lot! Any script/sql/wps script will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To open a workbook

```
dim wbk as workbook
set wbk=workbooks.open("c:\temp\wbk.xlsm")
```

To run macros on an another workbook

```
Application.Run "'wbk name.xlsm'!MacroToRun"
```